# Neo4j and .NET Core Identity Framework

Tags: neo4j, asp.net-core

I'm looking for a .NET Core Identity Framework implementation for Neo4j.

At this stage I can only find: [Neo4j.AspNet.Identity](https://github.com/DotNet4Neo4j/Neo4j.AspNet.Identity) but its not targeting .NET Core or .NET Standard.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to either alter the project to target .NET Core and/or .NET Standard or, know of an existing implementation that targets either of these.

Answer (score 2):

Future reference (for myself and others), cskardon has kindly created a NetStandard implementation for .NET Core. (Thanks cskardon!)

[A NetStandard implementation of Neo4j.AspNet.Identity](https://github.com/cskardon/Neo4j.AspNet.Identity.Core)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a .NET Core implementation, which is based on or inspired by Neo4j.AspNet.Identity (mentioned in previous answer):
https://github.com/francnuec/Neo4j.AspNetCore.Identity

As of July 2020, the above was last updated December 2019, whereas Neo4j.AspNet.Identity was last updated September 2017.